# Read/write all values of a std::multimap with a given key in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20

Suppose I have some function:

```
void mutate(V& v);
```

that reads/writes `v` -
and I want to write a function:

```
void mutate_map_values(std::multimap<K,V>& m, K k);
```

that applies `mutate` to all values of `m` that have key `k`.

What's the most succinct way to implement `mutate_map_values` in C++20?

Comment: What have you tried? What about your attempt(s) do you feel are not succinct enough?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Best solution I have so far is `.equal_range` example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range .  I'd like to know if there is a shorter way I am missing before I propose one to the C++ standards commitee.

Comment: Well that currently seems like the best way to find all elements of a specific key. It's not very succinct to iterate over elements of the same key using it though. Some kind of `for_each` member function might have been nice. But is it a common enough use-case that it should be added to the standard?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: My working theory is that iterating over all values of key k in a multimap is as common a use case as accessing the singular value of key k in a map (ie operator[]).

Comment: @Kerndog73: I don't think your `for_each` works because `mutate` operates on `V` not `std::pair<K,V>`.  `mutate` is just a proxy for some code that does something with a `V`.

Comment: In the linked example you could subsume the call to `equal_range` into the `init` expression of the `for` loop and use a structured binding such as `for (auto [i, e] = m.equal_range(key); i != e; ++i)`.  Other than that it's difficult to judge without seeing an example of the code you would *like* to be able to write.

Comment: @G.M.: I'm not sure yet but I was thinking: `for (V& v : m[k]) mutate(v);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::ranges::subrange`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.subrange) is a utility class that's constructible from anything that is like a pair of iterators. Which fits with what [`std::multimap::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) already returns. Combining the two, we may write the desired function as follows in C++20:

```
#include <ranges>

void mutate_map_values(std::multimap<K,V>& m, K k) {
    using namespace std::ranges;
    for (auto& [_, v] : subrange(m.equal_range(k))) {
        mutate(v);
    }
}
```